# Texture Baking in Cycles Lopsided

Tags: baking

This is a baked U.V. map of a bullet, but I detest that the specularity and lighting is influencing the image. I tried baking in other ways using blender 2.77; with indirect and direct light toggling, cancelling shadows, working lights, but nothing seems to create the result I'm after.
[image][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JyVKJ.png)
The baked image is lop sided with specularity, and when applying it in blender internal it looks 2 sided and ugly, I want it to be in uniform. The lighting is also messing with the glossiness and is decreasing the contrast. I don't seem to be having such problems with the normal and specularity maps. Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: @mrzak where do i check the anisotropic shader? Yes i was using cycles when baking, and i attached an image of the bake applied in blender internal.

Comment: I asked about Anisotropic shader because reflections on the top left baked image resemble ones obtained with it. In Cycles, shader is added into the materials node tree (I'm not sure you could add it without being aware of that).

Comment: @mrzak no i havent got any of them in any node trees

Comment: Image on the top right is darker in the bottom. Is that because of some reflections ? Or could it be that it's the same effect like on the mesh with map applied ? Was the normals' direction checked before baking and on the resulting mesh ? What is image in the bottom left, dark blueish one, is that bullet too ? Do you use normal maps ? And finally, are those images in the top what you'd like to achieve and one in the bottom what you get ? It's hard to get what's there going, probably some questions can point you in the right direction.

Comment: @mrzak the top left image is the butt of the bullet, top right is the outside body, bottom left is the inside, and the bottom right is some detail using the body's nodes. The top right image is darker on the bottom because of reflection, intend for it to be 1 color. Yes the normals maps were applied correctly. The image on the top is the bake and the image below all the text is the result. The main question is can i bake the maps without the reflection?

Comment: @mrzak i solved it -ish. I deleted all the lights, increased the background light, decreased the scene's gamma and increased the exposure. It worked well, but killed all the glossiness. I can live with that, but if you have a better suggestion, that would be appreciated. Thank you for your input